# "no function clause matching in Base.url_decode64/2" when making request to /admin/api/login

Tags: omisego

`@js` asked on Rocket Chat that when running the [dockerized version](https://hub.docker.com/r/omisego/ewallet/) of the eWallet server and making a request to `/admin/api/login` endpoint, a `FunctionClauseError` is raised as follow:

```ex
Request: POST /admin/api/login
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Base.url_decode64/2
        (elixir) lib/base.ex:482: Base.url_decode64(nil, [padding: false])
        (salty) lib/salty/utils.ex:18: Salty.Utils.decode_key/2
        (salty) lib/salty/secret_box.ex:53: Salty.SecretBox.decrypt/1
        (cloak) lib/cloak.ex:170: anonymous fn/3 in Cloak.decrypt/1
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1899: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
        (cloak) lib/cloak.ex:164: Cloak.decrypt/1
        (cloak) lib/cloak/types/encrypted_map_field.ex:26: Cloak.EncryptedMapField.load/1
        (ecto) lib/ecto/type.ex:647: Ecto.Type.process_loaders/3
```

This does not seem to happen when running the [vagrant version](https://github.com/omisego/ewallet#quick-installation-with-goban).

What can be done to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Depending on the environment you are actually running on:

1. **`dev` environment:** Force the instance to run as `dev` environment by setting the environment variable `ENV=dev`.
2. **`prod` environment:** Generate your own encryption keys and configure them into environment variables:

   ```ex
   EWALLET_SECRET_KEY=<your_secret_key>
   LOCAL_LEDGER_SECRET_KEY=<your_secret_key>
   ```

---

**Long version:**

This issue is quite tricky to investigate. It involves knowing that the eWallet uses [Cloak](https://hexdocs.pm/cloak/Cloak.html) to encrypt/decrypt information to/from the database.

Cloak requires a cipher module configured, which in this case is `Salty.SecretBox.Cloak`. It has the following code for decryption:

```ex
# deps/salty/lib/salty/secret_box_cloak.ex

def decrypt(<<tag::binary-1, ciphertext::binary>>) do
  config = Salty.Utils.get_config(:cloak, @module, tag)
  Salty.SecretBox.decrypt(
    %{
      key: config.key,
      payload: ciphertext
    }
  )
end
```

Notice the line `config = Salty.Utils.get_config(:cloak, @module, tag)`, it calls `Salty.Utils.get_config/3` to get the encryption/decryption key:

```ex
# deps/salty/lib/salty/utils.ex

def get_config(app, module, tag) do
  Application.get_env(app, module)
  |> Keyword.get(:keys)
  |> Enum.find(fn(key) -> key.tag == tag end)
end
```

Now if you take a look at our config files. While the `dev` environment has the key pre-configured, you'll see that on `prod` environment, the system would extract the key from the environment variable `EWALLET_SECRET_KEY`.

```ex
# apps/ewallet_db/config/prod.exs

key = System.get_env("EWALLET_SECRET_KEY")

config :cloak, Salty.SecretBox.Cloak,
       tag: "SBX",
       default: true,
       keys: [%{tag: <<1>>, key: key, default: true}]
```

So the solution, depending on the environment you intended to be on, is either:

1. **`dev` environment:** The docker image is set to run as `prod`. You can override this by setting the environment variable `ENV=dev`.
2. **`prod` environment:** Generate your own encryption keys and configure them into environment variables:

   ```ex
   EWALLET_SECRET_KEY=<your_secret_key>
   LOCAL_LEDGER_SECRET_KEY=<your_secret_key>
   ```